# How can I "normalize" one data set based on a third variable?

Tags: normalization

My data set is divided into two groups: (1) patients who received physical therapy and (2) patients who did not.

Our primary outcome is looking at how long it took them for their symptoms to resolve (symptom resolution).

However, the group who received physical therapy initially had "worse symptoms" (based on our post-concussion symptom scale - PCSS).

How can I "normalize" our primary outcome (symptom resolution) based on this other variable (PCSS scores)? I imagine that the time for symptom resolution after this adjustment will be lower.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way would be to include the baseline score as a covariate in your regression model. This would adjust for group differences in the score prior to treatment.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to compare the the ratio of symptom resolution to PCSS scores for all combinations. For example lets say your data looked liked this:

```
pt, PCSS, symptom resolution (days)
0, 2, 5
1, 4, 3
```

We could calculate:

```
pt = 0: 5/2 = 2.5
pt = 1: 3/4 = 0.75
```

Example result: Patients that did NOT receive physical therapy had a higher ratio of resolution:PCSS compared to patient who did recieve PT

A more rigorous and fun way could be could be difference-in-differences causal modeling and synthetic controls. [This resource](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/15-Synthetic-Control.html) by Matheus Facure Alves is amazing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).